# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/CellScannable

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Hi I am getting below exception in Hadoop HBase Java API, while creating a new Table.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/CellScannable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.aztec.fn.policy.hbase.rest.client.HBaseRestAPITest.main(HBaseRestAPITest.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellScannable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Obvious question: is the class `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellScannable` present in the classpath? Are you using Maven?

Comment: You probably have a JAR file missing when you run the program, or you have compiled your program with one version of Hadoop, but you are running it with a different version.